# ExtJS 4.2.1 How to organize Viewport space

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewport, extjs4.2

Here is code which works fine:

"ObjectsGrid" is a Ext.grid.Panel component with lots of rows.

```
Ext.application({
    requires    : ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name        : 'crm',
    appFolder   : 'app',
    controllers : ['Controller'],
    launch      : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            id      : "MainViewPort",
            layout  : 'fit',
            applyTo : Ext.getBody(),
            items   : [
                {
                    xtype: 'ObjectsGrid'

                }]
        });
    }
});
```

But when I try to organize Viewport space by adding some panels (with same ObjectsGrid inside), all grid rows disappears. Looks like grid has moved outside the Viewport:

```
Ext.application({
    requires    : ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name        : 'crm',
    appFolder   : 'app',
    controllers : ['Controller'],
    launch      : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        title : 'main panel',
        layout: 'fit',
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px',
        applyTo : Ext.getBody(),
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                border: false,
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        html: 'upper panel',
                        height: 20,
                        margin: '0 0 5 0'
                    },{
                        xtype: 'ObjectsGrid'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
    }
});
```

My grid component:

```
Ext.define('crm.view.ObjectsGrid' ,{
        extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
        id          : "ObjectsGrid",
        alias       : 'widget.ObjectsGrid',
        store       : 'ObjectFormStore',
        title       : 'title',
        stripeRows  : false,
.....
```

Whats wrong with my grid?

And is it normal for big application to organize Viewport space with panels component?

There must be some "best practice"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whats wrong with my grid?

It is missing [`flex`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox-cfg-flex) config value. Try this:

```
{
    xtype: 'ObjectsGrid',
    flex: 1
}
```

> is it normal for big application to organize Viewport space with
>   panels component?

It's OK if you *need* a panel *and* it is actually [Ext.panel.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel) that you need (versus say just an [Ext.container.Container](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container)). In your example, the panel bearing `vbox` layout looks redundant: you could specify your `vbox` layout on the viewport directly (instead of `fit`).

> There must be some "best practice"?

Decide what you need from usability/UX perspective. Build it with minimal complexity. Keep everything necessary / reasonable / rational. Don't let redundant stuff in, etc. etc.

P. S. If you are starting a new app from scratch, better use the latest version of ExtJS.